# Form.as_p works fine but individual form fields is not submitting correctly

Tags: django, django-forms

I have set up my template by import my form with form.as_p before, and it works fine. However, I need to specify each field, as I have a field that I don't want the user to see (and I need to have it in my django admin so I can't exclude it from the form).

However, when I set-up the form with it's individual fields, and submit it, I don't get redirected, I just get back to the filled out form.

I have set-up a number of print fields, and have also tried to print in form_invalid but nothing shows up, I have no idea what the issue is. Can someone suggest how to fix this or maybe solve it another way?

The form in the template

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="adForm" data-municipalities-url="{% url 'ajax_load_municipalities' %}" data-areas-url="{% url 'ajax_load_areas' %}" novalidate>
    {% csrf_token %}  

    <!-- {{ form.as_p }} -->

    {{ form.non_field_errors }}

    <div class="fieldWrapper">
      {{ form.province.errors }}
      {{ form.province.label_tag }}
      {{ form.province }}
    </div>

    <div class="fieldWrapper">
      {{ form.municipality.errors }}
      {{ form.municipality.label_tag }}
      {{ form.municipality }}
    </div>

    <div class="fieldWrapper">
      {{ form.area.errors }}
      {{ form.area.label_tag }}
      {{ form.area }}
    </div>

    <div class="fieldWrapper">
      {{ form.name.errors }}
      {{ form.name.label_tag }}
      {{ form.name }}
    </div>

    <div class="fieldWrapper">
      {{ form.age.errors }}
      {{ form.age.label_tag }}
      {{ form.age }}
    </div>

    <div class="fieldWrapper">
      {{ form.title.errors }}
      {{ form.title.label_tag }}
      {{ form.title }}
    </div>

    <div class="fieldWrapper">
      {{ form.description.errors }}
      {{ form.description.label_tag }}
      {{ form.description }}
    </div>

    <div class="fieldWrapper">
      {{ form.days_per_week.errors }}
      {{ form.days_per_week.label_tag }}
      {{ form.days_per_week }}
    </div>

    <div class="fieldWrapper">
      {{ form.hundras.errors }}
      {{ form.hundras.label_tag }}
      {{ form.hundras }}
    </div>

    <div class="fieldWrapper">
      {{ form.size_offered.errors }}
      {{ form.size_offered.label_tag }}
      {{ form.size_offered }}
    </div>

    <div class="fieldWrapper">
      {{ form.image1.errors }}
      {{ form.image1.label_tag }}
      {{ form.image1 }}
    </div>

    <div class="fieldWrapper">
      {{ form.image2.errors }}
      {{ form.image2.label_tag }}
      {{ form.image2 }}
    </div>

    <div class="fieldWrapper">
      {{ form.image3.errors }}
      {{ form.image3.label_tag }}
      {{ form.image3 }}
    </div>

    <div class="fieldWrapper">
      {{ form.payment_type.errors }}
      {{ form.payment_type.label_tag }}
      {{ form.payment_type }}
    </div>



    <button type="submit">Publicera annons</button>

  </form>
```

The view

```
class NewAdTakeMyDog(CreateView):
    model = Advertisement
    form_class = NewAdTakeMyDogForm
    template_name = 'core/advertisement_form_take.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('view_ads_take_my_dog')

    def __init__(self):
        print('init')
        self.pk = None


    def form_valid(self, form):
        print('Form valid')
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        form.instance.is_offering_own_dog = True
        form.instance.is_published = False
        response = super().form_valid(form)
        return response

    def get_success_url(self):
        print('Get success url')
        if self.object.payment_type == 'S':
            return reverse('swish_payment_template', kwargs={'pk': self.object.pk})
        if self.object.payment_type == 'B':
            return reverse('bg_payment', kwargs={'pk': self.object.pk})
```

forms.py

```
class NewAdTakeMyDogForm(forms.ModelForm):
    
    CHOICES = [('S',f'Swish - {PRICE_SWISH}'),('B',f'Bankgiro - {PRICE_BANKGIRO}')]
    payment_type = forms.CharField(label='Betalsätt', widget=forms.RadioSelect(choices=CHOICES))

    hundras = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=DogBreeds.objects.all(),
        widget=autocomplete.ModelSelect2(url='breed-autocomplete')
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Advertisement
        fields = ('author', 'province', 'municipality', 'area', 'title', 'name', 'age', 'description', 'days_per_week', 'size_offered', 'hundras', 'image1', 'image2', 'image3', 'payment_type')


    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(NewAdTakeMyDogForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['municipality'].queryset = Municipality.objects.none()
        self.fields['area'].queryset = Area.objects.none()
        self.fields['area'].required = False

        if 'province' in self.data:
            try:
                # Set municipality queryset
                province_id = int(self.data.get('province'))
                self.fields['municipality'].queryset = Municipality.objects.filter(province_id=province_id).order_by('name')
            
                # Set area queryset
                municipality_id = int(self.data.get('municipality'))
                self.fields['area'].queryset = Area.objects.filter(municipality_id=municipality_id).order_by('name')
                

            except (ValueError, TypeError) as e:
                pass # invalid input from the client; ignore and fallback to empty Municipality/Area queryset
```

Comment: Had you checked [django-crispy-forms](https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)?

Comment: Hi @YevgeniyKosmak, Yes I've tried it as well now but still same issue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving the issue by creating an additional form, which I use for the Admin interface.

Also I got crispy forms to work by using:

```
{{form|crispy}}
```

instead of:

```
{% crispy form %}
```